# Selector with image and textview at the same time

Tags: android

I know how to make a selector for imageview and how to do it for textView ,now i have a tabwidget that contains tabs each tab have image and text view below it , my question is how to change the background of the image view and the color o it text view when the user click on the tab .

Comment: What hae you tried? Show us some code.

Comment: [You should consider searching before posting, this question is fairly common around the web.](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/User_Interface/tab_layout) [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) is generally used for more for specific programming questions. Keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [TabHost.TabSpec.setIndicator(View view)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setIndicator%28android.view.View%29) to define your own layout where you set your selectors. You can reuse `tab_indicator.xml` layout, can be found in `platforms/android-xx/data/res/drawable`.

excerpt:

```
mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

private View createTabView(CharSequence label, Drawable icon) {
    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, mTabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    tv.setText(label);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon).
    iv.setDrawable(icon);
    return tabIndicator;
}

public void addTab(CharSequence label, Drawable icon) {
    View tabIndicator = createTabView(label, icon);
    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(label.toString()).setIndicator(tabIndicator).setContent(...);
    mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}
```